# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in - error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I run this:

```
while ($array = $queryGallery->fetch_assoc()) {
    $gallery[] = $array;
}
```

I end up with the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in .

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Put your error message in google search bar . you will get thousands of answer .

Comment: Can you explain what you trying to achieve in your 'while' statement?